# Is Reflection Class a good pratice?

Tags: design-patterns, reflection

I have an API which receives some data in JSON format. Depending on the attributes of JSON, the API will instantiate a class.

Is it a good practice to use reflection class for things like this, because the reflection will solve all my problems?

I just want to know whether is it ok to do this or I should avoid reflection?

Comment: This is sort of like asking if using a screwdriver is good practice.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not a good practice. You should always avoid reflection.
I had a similar experience, it will limit you in taking advantage of the middleware abilities and best practices.

The responsiblity you are trying to implement is called Routing.
The best practice is to avoid implement routing. Then you have clean and a well-defined API.

The way you are implementing the API, you will end up with an API contract that depends on the implementation detail of the underlying code, it is bad.

Instead try to use and configure the middleware routing abolities, to route requests to proper controllers.

The underlying classes should be wrapped by Controllers. The controllers transform data and decide which function to be called.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I will implement this using routes with controller.